# element height after content change

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I have a snippet of code that alters the contents of a DIV to match the contents of a textarea and then applies the height change in the DIV to the textarea element.

```
<textarea class="fieldEdit" data-fieldid="1_description"></textarea>
<div class="hiddenDiv" data-fieldid="1_description"></div>

<Script>
$('.fieldEdit').live('keyup', function(){growTextArea(this)});

function growTextArea(parameter) {
// works
     $('div').find("[data-fieldid='1_description']").text($(parameter).val());
     $("[data-fieldid='1_description']").text($(parameter).val());

// No Works
     height = $('div').find("[data-fieldid='1_description']").outerHeight();
     height = $("[data-fieldid='1_description']").outerHeight();
     alert(height);

// Works
     heightDiv = $('.hiddenDiv').outerHeight();
     alert(heightDiv);

     $(parameter).css('height', $('div').find("[data-fieldid='1_description']").outerHeight());
}
</script>
```

The DIV contents change properly, so the search function is working properly, however the search function always returns the original height of the DIV.  The function is called by onKeyUp in the textarea.  If the .find is swapped out for a .hiddenDiv the height change is reflected properly.

Comment: JSFiddle exampe maybe? And which `.find` do you swap for `.hiddenDiv`?

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kKqWG/1/) what you're after?

Comment: There was actually a typo the 'no works' whould have started $('div').find...

Comment: Roberts solution was a different approach and works but I I was trying to avoid hard coding a class or ID to identify the DIV element, instead using a data attribute.
I'm not sure why the jquery .find() allows me to change the contents but not retrieve current height attribute...
I can't seem to get jsfiddle to search by data attribute so I Can't show a working version atm.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the jQuery promise function. Something like:

```
$('#divId').html(someText).promise().done(function(){
        // check height now
    });
```